# What sci fi book series did a Viver appear in?

Tags: story-identification, trope, transhuman

I read this at local library once, I liked it, but title has always escapes me. It sort of followed the unlikely hero trope. The one thing that I clearly remember were the Viver. These were not aliens, but transhumans. I recall them being warrior culture, with natural body armor.

Comment: "Viver" appears to be the Portuguese verb for "to live".

Comment: I remember reading this book, but not the title. As I recall: 

The name "Vivors" was short for "survivors", and the species was a genetically-modified human variant that was very good at surviving.  As adults, they were cautious and rarely seen off their planet, but as adolescents they actively sought adventure and danger to prove their survivorship abilities.  

Memorable as they clearly are, they were far from central to the story, with just a couple of them on a spaceship and mostly mentioned in passing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be *Spacer: Window of the Mind*, by John Maddox Roberts, or the related book *Space Angel*. Credit where credit is due: the presence of the name "Vivers" makes this easy to find, and others have done it before I. I can't search inside the book, but there's still some background. See [this question](http://askville.amazon.com/book-journey-center-galaxy-Vivers/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=29115459) or [this one.](http://www.librarything.com/topic/193492)

Comment: I done some searching over the years but it hard to filter results if you only remember one element. It is _**Spacer: Window of the Mind**_, early '80s edition. While tracking down the Space Angel descriptions I saw cover for Spacer, I distinctly remember that cover. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Oh, I wasn't trying to criticize you; I was just trying to avoid taking credit for what was mostly the work of others.