# Old book about an alien encased in a deposit of diamond

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space-exploration

I'm looking for the name of an old sci-fi book. In it, a spaceship’s crew goes to a planet to mine a large deposit of diamond. However, they find an alien entity encased in the diamond. They also go to the center of the galaxy in the story.

Comment: they take a trip to the center of the galaxy

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Did they take the trip to the center of the galaxy before finding the planet? After? In the process of?

Comment: @jtcoulter Was it a long book or a novella?

Answer (score 11):

[*Space Angel*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6489) by John Maddox Roberts

[image: Space Angel front cover]

An independant trader starship learns of a wilderness planet with an outcropping of valuable diamond slab. They discover a metal sphere inside the diamond. This turns out to be a billion year old weakly godlike entity who needs their help. A rival entity is Occupying the galactic core, and the first entity needs transportation.

Along the way they enlist the help of two "Vivers", who are warlike mutated humans. They also get help from an alien crab like being who is a poet.

Comment: I'm so glad this has been identified... I'd read the sequel 'Windows of the Mind' a long time ago and vowed at the time that I would one day find and read the first book (a vow long forgotten until I saw this Q and A!)

Comment: question about sequel answered and accepted at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107903/what-sci-fi-book-series-did-a-viver-appear-in/107995

Comment: @WinchellChung Where did the summary come from?

Comment: @Stormblessed I wrote the summary from my memory of reading the novel many times. take it for what it is worth

Comment: @WinchellChung Good memory! I couldn’t do that, even with *Skulduggery Pleasant*, which I’ve read and re-read a LOT!

Comment: What does god need with a starship?